# Using PowerShell vs. cmd.exe in SharePoint development?

Tags: powershell

I've just started reading various books on SharePoint development and have come across a wonderful tool called PowerShell. From the looks of it, it could replace the old DOS tool cmd.exe. There are a few blogs discussing PowerShell vs. cmd.exe, but I have found none really useful one discussing PowerShell vs. cmd.exe in the eyes of a SharePoint developer.

Simply put, is it possible to only use PowerShell as the only command line tool as a SharePoint developer, or do you still rely on cmd.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no task you couldn't do with PS because it allows to work with any .NET objects. The stsadm tool is considered obsolete now - the most commands [have](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621084.aspx) the equivalents in SharePoint PS commandlets. And for the [unsupported](http://blogs.interfacett.com/spike-xavier2011-5-26-stsadm-commands-that-have-no-powershell-equivalent-sharepoint) stsadm options you can still use stsadm even through PS as it's [able](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters.aspx) to execute standard command line tools. So you definitely can work with PS alone.

Comment: Thanx, just what I needed, and wanted to hear!

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do much using cmd.exe in terms of working with sharepoint. the key difference between cmd.exe and powershell when it comes to sharepoint is the fact that yuo can use C# assemblies within powershell. this allows you to access sharepoint core libraries from within powershell. This functionality is not available in cmd.exe. So you will only use powershell as your cmd line tool.